# How to check python codes by reduction?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import numpy
def rtpairs(R,T):
    for i in range(numpy.size(R)):
        o=0.0
        for j in range(T[i]):
            o +=2*(numpy.pi)/T[i]
            yield R[i],o
R=[0.0,0.1,0.2]
T=[1,10,20]
for r,t in genpolar.rtpairs(R,T):
plot(r*cos(t),r*sin(t),'bo')
```

This program is supposed to be a generator, but I would like to check if i'm doing the right thing by first asking it to return some values for pheta (see below)

```
import numpy as np
def rtpairs (R=None,T=None):
    R = np.array(R)
    T = np.array(T)
    for i in range(np.size(R)):
        pheta = 0.0   
        for j in range(T[i]):
            pheta += (2*np.pi)/T[i]
            return pheta
```

Then 
I typed import omg as o in the prompt

```
x = [o.rtpairs(R=[0.0,0.1,0.2],T=[1,10,20])]
# I tried to collect all values generated by the loops
```

It turns out to give me only one value which is 2 pi ... I have a habit to check my codes in the half way through, Is there any way for me to get a list of angles by using the code above? I don't understand why I must use a generator structure to check (first one) , but I couldn't use normal loop method to check.

Normal loop e.g.

```
x=[i for i in range(10)]
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Here I can see a list of values I should get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            return pheta
```

You switched to `return` instead of `yield`. It isn't a generator any more; it's stopping at the first return. Change it back.

```
x = [o.rtpairs(R=[0.0,0.1,0.2],T=[1,10,20])]
```

This wraps the `rtpairs` return value in a 1-element list. That's not what you want. If you want to extract all elements from a generator and store them in a list, call `list` on the generator:

```
x = list(o.rtpairs(R=[0.0,0.1,0.2],T=[1,10,20]))
```

Comment: Hi,user2357112, it says float object is not iterable ... so weird

Comment: I was trying  to do the easiest things to check if my codes are still doing fine before proceeding to generators